# Returning results is very slow in multiprocess code. What should I do?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**No multiprocessing code:**

```
from time import time

func1Results = []

def func1(valList):
    num = 0

    for val in valList:
        num += val

    func1Results.append(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = time()
    
    for valList in [range(40000000), range(40000000), range(40000000), range(40000000)]:
        func1(valList)

    ed = time()
    
    for r in func1Results:
        print(r)

    print(ed - st)
```

> Output: 
> 799999980000000 
> 799999980000000 
> 799999980000000 
> 799999980000000 
> 13.679119348526001

**Multiprocess code:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import time

queue = Queue()
processList, func1Results = [], []

def func1(valList, queue):
    num = 0

    for val in valList:
        num += val

    queue.put(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = time()

    for valList in [range(40000000), range(40000000), range(40000000), range(40000000)]:
        xProcess = Process(target=func1, args=(valList, queue))
        xProcess.start()
        
        func1Results.append(queue.get()), processList.append(xProcess)

    for xProcess in processList:
        xProcess.join()

    ed = time()

    for i in func1Results:
        print(i)

    print(ed - st)
```

> Output: 
> 799999980000000 
> 799999980000000 
> 799999980000000 
> 799999980000000 
> 13.916456937789917

When I use the 'Put' and 'Get' commands, the processing time of the multiprocessing code increases significantly. I know that returning results in multiprocessing is quite time consuming. But this is exactly what I need. What can I do to return the result more efficiently?

Comment: Your code is effectively synchronous because the subprocess doesn't terminate until it's placed something on the queue and you don't start another process until you get something back on the queue

Comment: Yes, there is no need to look into the `queue` until after calling `.join()` on all the processes.

Comment: When I delete the 'equeu.get()' function and print the 'num' with the 'print' variable at the end of the 'fun1' function, the completion speed of the process drops to 5.5 seconds. What would you suggest I do for a nested loop where I need a return?

Comment: I don't understand what you said, but it sounds like a different question. You should look into the answer below to see if it helps with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a restructured approach to the original code where we allow all the sub-processes to terminate before we examine the queue.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager
from functools import partial
import time

N = 40000000

def calc(q, rng):
    num = 0
    for n in rng:
        num += n
    q.put(num)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        queue = manager.Queue()
        rlist = [range(N), range(N), range(N), range(N)]
        p = partial(calc, queue)
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(p, rlist)
        while not queue.empty():
            print(queue.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration = {end-start:.2f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
799999980000000
799999980000000
799999980000000
799999980000000
Duration = 1.93s
```

**Note:**

Of course, you don't need a queue to get the results from the sub-process. You could just do this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

N = 40000000

def calc(rng):
    num = 0
    for n in rng:
        num += n
    return num

def main():
    rlist = [range(N), range(N), range(N), range(N)]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print(*executor.map(calc, rlist), sep='\n')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration = {end-start:.2f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
799999980000000
799999980000000
799999980000000
799999980000000
Duration = 1.83s
```

Comment: @TahirÖzcan I appreciate that you're learning but bear in mind that *calc()* could simply be implemented as *return sum(rng)* - i.e., no explicit loop. That would be **much** faster